# Is there way to chain tarfile generation and gnupg encryption in python?

Tags: python, gnupg, tarfile

I want to make a tar file of a directory and encrypt the tar file.

Currently, I create a tar file and save it into HDD. And then, I read the tar file to encrypt and save the encrypted version.

But my problem is I don't need the tar file and erase it at the end of the process.
Hence, I feel the writing of the tar file is a wasting of time.

My code looks like this in a simple form:

```
import tarfile
import gnupg

......

with tarfile.open(name = tarpath, mode = 'w:xz') as tar:
    for afile in files:
        tar.add(name = afile)

......

with open(tarpath, 'rb') as tarstream:
    gpg.encrypt_file(tarstream, fingerprint, output = outpath)
```

With the first half part of the code, the tar file is saved into the disk. Can I avoid this step and chain the tar result into the input of the gpg directly?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `BytesIO` class. The `BytesIO` class is a file-like object that handles streams of bytes.

```py
import tarfile
import gnupg
from io import BytesIO

tarstream = BytesIO()

with tarfile.open(fileobj = tarstream, mode = 'w:xz') as tar:
    for afile in files:
        tar.add(name = afile)

tarstream.seek(0)
gpg.encrypt_file(tarstream, fingerprint, output = outpath)
```

Key points to notice are:

- the additional import
- the manual instantiation of tarstream as `BytesIO()`
- the `fileobj` argument instead of the `name` argument
- The manual resetting of the cursor before encrypting with GPG.

---

#### Recommended Alternative

As discussed in the comments, using a file is better so as to avoid memory issues where your data is too large. If you do not want to worry about remembering to manually delete the file, you can use `tempfile.TemporaryFile` which automatically deletes the file when it is closed.

```py
import tarfile
import gnupg
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

with TemporaryFile(mode='w+b') as tarstream:
    with tarfile.open(fileobj = tarstream, mode = 'w:xz') as tar:
        for afile in files:
            tar.add(name = afile)

    tarstream.seek(0)
    gpg.encrypt_file(tarstream, fingerprint, output = outpath)
```

Comment: And perhaps also, if the file ends up being bigger than your RAM, you will run into serious thrashing and/or OOM errors.

Comment: @tripleee is there a way to work around the memory problem? My files are gigabytes in size. And I'm doing the encryption using multi-threading.

Comment: Writing to disk after all sounds like absolutely the simplest solution to that. If the `tarfile` component can be persuaded to produce a stream of output that GPG can read and write out to disk as it arrives, that should also work. See the `'w|'` description in the `tarfile` documentation.

Comment: Random googling also got me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568166/pipe-stream-gnupg-output-to-tarfile-in which however discusses decryption, not encryption.

Comment: Agree that writing a file to disk is the simplest solution. You can look into using [tempfile.TemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) to create the `tarfile`. This should automatically destroy the `tarfile` when you `.close()` it. So using it in a `with` block that wraps the rest of your code should do it.

Comment: I will update my answer with an example of what I mean.